# Excel VBA create folder using two cell columns

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I am trying to create folders using the VBA MkDir command. I have a worksheet column with 001, 002, 003... and next to that a column with the names of cities (e.g.) London, Birmingham, Manchester...; I am trying to create folders that go 001 London, 002 Birmingham etc

I can create folders using values from one column but not two; I can either make them called 001, 002 etc or London, Birmingham etc. If I put the cities and numbers in same cell I lose the leading zeros, which I want to keep.

What code should I use to combine values from two columns into the folder name, i.e how do I use VBA to create folders 001 London, 002 Birmingham? Thanks

Comment: You need `Format` (with VBA) or TEXT (with formulas) to keep the leading zeros.

Comment: Sorry, very new to excel, are you saying I can use TEXT command to keep leading zeros in a cell with numbers and text? Currently, when I add text, the leading zeros go away.

Comment: To expound - you can concatenate the two columns into a new column and use TEXT to keep the leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CreateDir()
 Set activSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
 p1 = ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value
 p2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value
 newFolder = p1 + "_" + p2
 MkDir newFOlder
 Debug.Print "New folder under: " + CurDir() + newFOlder

 '' RmDir newFOlder

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAeVm.png)

Comment: Consider editing your answer to include an explanation of what your solution does and how it does it per [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)